# How to build fontconfigration library for ios

Tags: ios

i am looking for the way to generate a libfonfig for iOS 8.
maybe use using terminal or shell file...
Could you help me.

How to use following commands:

```
/etc/fonts/fonts.conf
/etc/fonts/conf.d
$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/fontconfig/conf.d
$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/fontconfig/fonts.conf
~/.fonts.conf.d
~/.fonts.conf
```